# Define an interface with a channel in Go

Tags: go

Can I define an interface with a channel in Go?  I would like to define an interface that would allow me to use objects of different types that would all have the same channel defined.  EXE:

```
type I interface {
    chan Communications []byte
    otherMethod()
}
```

(This give syntax error: unexpected token chan.  I tried a few different syntaxes and some googling with no avail.)

Comment: You should probably check the documentation before asking: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface does not hold data, it defines what something implements.

You could have a method that returns a channel. eg:

```
type I interface {
    getChannel() (chan []byte)
    otherMethod()
}
```

Please read up on interfaces. The [tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) would help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I followed through the tour before posting but was hoping that there was more functionality than was documented there.  I guess I've been programming too much C++ lately.  Your method will work, it just means extra function calls whereas direct access to a channel in the interface would be faster and have simpler looking code.

Comment: I know they are just examples. but I think it is better to use exported methods in interface as example because that is the majority of the use cases